# Authentication error while connecting to MongoDB from remote host

Tags: mongodb

New to MongoDB, trying to figure out how permissions work.

My PHP code connects to Mongo just fine:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient('mongodb://admin:password@localhost');
return $mongo->selectDB('admin');
```

I can also do this from shell:

```
# mongo -u admin -p password admin
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.5
connecting to: admin
```

However, an attempt to connect to Mongo from other remote host using the same credentials (Windows, in this case) results in:

> Failed to authenticate admin@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document

I am trying to configure *Robomongo* admin tool to manage MongoDB instance.

Obviously, I've allowed connections to Mongo server by updating IP binding directive.

It looks like "admin" user is not allowed to connect from a host other than localhost - MySQL has exactly the same parameter.

The question: how do I allow **admin** user to connect from outside the box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I had to do.

1. Drop all existing admin users.
2. To configure authentication mechanism, start mongodb WITHOUT authorization: "enabled". Then:

> mongo admin

From mongo shell:

```
var schema = db.system.version.findOne({"_id" : "authSchema"})
schema.currentVersion = 3
db.system.version.save(schema)
db.createUser(
{
  user: "admin",
  pwd: "password",
  roles: [ "root" ]
}
```

)

and restart with authorization: "enabled".